# Abrir modal através do ActionResult no MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Olá, estou construindo uma página de cadastro com MVC .NET e estou com uma dificuldade. Quero validar as informações preenchidas, caso estejam corretas, vou seguir o fluxo da aplicação porém caso não, quero abrir uma modal jquery alertando o usuário que existem informações incorretas. Como sou novo no MVC ainda não consegui isso. Criei a div com a modal e a chamo através do click do botão, mas não consegui colocar essa condição de abrir apenas quando meu post não tiver sucesso.

Abaixo segue a div com a modal que criei.

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4>ATENÇÃO!</h4>
                        <p>
                            Existem informações inconsistentes em seu cadastro.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então vamos lá...

Um exemplo simples...

Contoller:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(String user, String senha)
{
    if (user == "user" && senha == "senha")
        //Acesso autorizado
        return RedirectToAction("PaginaUser");
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Acesso Negado";
        return View();
    }

}

public ActionResult PaginaUser()
{
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<h2>Login</h2>
@if (ViewBag.Message == "Acesso Negado")
{
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>ACESSO NEGADO!</h4>
                <p>
                    Verifique seu login e senha.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Login</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Login", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Senha", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Senha, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: Deu certinho meu amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!